# Volume of tetrahedron via scalar triple product

Tags: geometry

Say I have tetrahedron with vertices that have position vectors $\vec 0$, $\vec u$, $\vec v$, $\vec w$ and show that the volume is $\frac{1}{6} [\vec u,\vec v,\vec w]$. I know that $[\vec u,\vec v,\vec w]$ is the volume of a parallelepiped but I can't see how two can be related. Thanks

Comment: volume of a pyramid (or cone) = area of base $\times$ height $\div \,3$

Comment: For example if you take a unit cube $0 \le x, y, z \le 1$ and then divide it into regions depending on the order of $x,y,z$ then you get $3!$ congruent tetrahedra.  e.g. the region where $0 < x < y < z < 1$ is the interior of the tetrahedron with vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(0,0,1)$, $(0,1,1)$, $(1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume of a tetrahedron with base area $A$ and height $h$ is $\dfrac {A\times h}3.$

In this case, the base is a triangle, which has $\dfrac12$ the area of a face of the parallelepiped.

Therefore, the volume of the tetrahedron is $\dfrac16$ that of the parallelepiped.

Comment: Note:  you could see the factor $\frac13$ coming in, because, if you integrate along the height, the area of a cross-section is proportional to the square of the height, and the anti-derivative of $h^2$ is $\color{blue}{\dfrac13}h^3$